# Associated records get overwritten when changing one record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, associations

When i try to edit the value of a column of one record, which is associated to a parent record (e.g. Jobs has many Jobdetails) every record gets overwritten instead of just this one record.

For example: a job has many jobdetails. I want to be able to edit the `title` of one jobdetail. when i save the record it works but every other jobdetail belonging to the job has the same title now. The creation of new records works without problems, only the editing is making troubles.

**Models**
Jobs `has_many :jobdetails`
Jobdetail `belongs_to :job`

**Routes**

```
resources :jobs do
   resources :jobdetails
end
```

**Jobdetails_controller.rb**

```
def edit
  @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
  @jobdetail = Jobdetail.find(params[:id])
end


def update
  @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
  @jobdetail.update(jobdetail_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @job.jobdetails.update(jobdetail_params)
      format.html { redirect_to job_jobdetail_path(@job, @jobdetail), notice: 'Jobdetail was successfully updated.' }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @jobdetail.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end


def set_jobdetail
  @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
  @jobdetail = Jobdetail.find(params[:id])
end
```

i think the duplicated syntax in set_jobdetail and in the edit action are not necessary.
I tried several different syntaxes but they all wont work. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the line that's doing a "massive" update:

```
if @job.jobdetails.update(jobdetail_params)
```

To do a single one:

```
if @jobdetail.update(jobdetail_params)
```

With `@job.jobdetails.update` you're getting all the jobdetails associated to @job, and updating all of them with the values from jobdetail_params. As you've already initialized the specific jobdetail you want to update (`@jobdetail = Jobdetail.find(params[:id])`), you must to invoke `update` on that object.

Comment: your answer solved my problem. thanks for that! i honestly thought that the if statement would only ... check if there is something and would not execute a certain action :D

Comment: Sometimes it can be confusing, but it only checks if the result is truthy by invoking the method, which gives you some lines less. Glad to help.